# Making row of recyclerview invisible (First row)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i want to know how i can hide the specified row in my recycler-row-layout. I specified my row in a seperate layout and it will show as the first row. thanks alot, ill rate your comments. sry for bad language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get the position of your Item and then remove it from RecyclerView List.

```
int position = YOUR_RECYCLERVIEW_ITEM_POSITION;
yourList.remove(position);
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To keep your data backed up somewhere, create another ArrayList. Get the item from your original list and add this item to the new list.

```
ObjectClass o = yourList.get(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
int position = YOUR_RECYCLERVIEW_ITEM_POSITION;
yourList.remove(position);
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```